# Plotting parts of a polynomial

Tags: bugs, polynomials, partitions

**Bug introduced in 12.2 or earlier and persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

Consider the following polynomial

```
fun = 2 x + 34 x^2 - 5 y + 4 y^3;
```

when I try `fun[[1]]` I get `34 x^2`, but when I try

```
Plot[fun[[2]], {x, 0, 10}]
```

I get nothing, why? what is the best way to work with each term of a polynomial?

Comment: try `Plot[Evaluate@fun[[2]], {x, 0, 10}]`?

Comment: @DanielHuber then why it plots `fun[[1]]` correctly?

Comment: Something weird is going on (at least on my machine/fresh start). I can see and compute `fun[[1]]` to be `2x` but it keeps plotting `34 x^2` instead.  Without the Evaluate (of course) this returns a plot for a parabola, which is not correct. `Plot[fun[[1]], {x, -10, 10}]`

Comment: @Syed this is what I told in above comment

Comment: @kglr Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: You are right, this looks like a bug to me. Please report it to: support@wolfram.com

Comment: @DanielHuber Can you please edit the question to include the bugs tag/header and possibly say where this might be coming from? Thanks.

Comment: I can only guess. The fact that "Evaluate" fixes it points to Plot having the attribute "HoldAll"

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer.

---

```
$Version
```

"12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)"

---

Let me recreate what I am seeing on my machine:

```
fun = 2 x + 34 x^2 - 5 y + 4 y^3;

TreeForm[fun]
```

[image]

```
{fun[[1]], fun[[2]], fun[[3]], fun[[4]]}
```

> ```
> {2 x, 34 x^2, -5 y, 4 y^3}
> ```

```
GraphicsRow[{Plot[fun[[1]], {x, -10, 10}]
  , Plot[Evaluate@fun[[1]], {x, -10, 10}]
  }]
```

[image]

It looks like a bug.